# SignalR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

VS 2013 WebForms template with bootstrap. And I've got

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

( used to try `signalr/hubs` and `ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs")` etc... )

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly connection
        var chat = $.connection.chat;
```

I used to try various variants and used to search a lot about this trouble but still can't find solution for now. When I check loaded page sources and click on `signalr/hubs` I can see proxies loaded there and I also can see chat there.

But I still receive `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined`

- How can I debug it?
- Why could this happen?

Comment: simply means connection (in $.connection) is undefined. Try other ways to reference this connection object(like window.connection if its global variable)

Comment: @jsjunkie I don't know I think it's somewhere in SignalR API

Comment: Type javascript:alert($.connection) in you browsers address bar and if doesn't alerts "undefined" then check that you are importing js files before you have written your javascript function. If you get "undefined" then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310554/signalr-javascript-hub-proxies

Comment: @jsjunkie it said undefined

Comment: I got one more link to your problem. Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179644/signalr-connection-is-undefined

Comment: @jsjunkie thank I already tried it, for now still no effect.

Comment: Do you have a hub called chat?

Comment: @Kao yes, ported from old working project but it was using older signalr / jquery versions

Comment: Check the paths of your scripts...

Comment: @Kao which scripts? chat hub class is in Hub directory and compiled. I think it should be added with `app.MapSignalR();`

Comment: If $.connection is undefined it sounds like the js files are not found, so the paths to the js files.

Comment: Actually, it seems someone else has the same problem. Try seeing if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179644/signalr-connection-is-undefined?lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `$.connection` is not set, then the SignalR initialization code in jquery.signalR-*.min.js is not running or at least not finishing as expected. A possible cause might be having multiple jQuery versions included on the page (the VS templates add a reference, so if you added another one manually, this might be the problem). In that case, the `window.$` instance which SignalR set itself up in is simply being replaced by the second jQuery initialization script which sets `window.$` again.
If that is not it, you should try replacing the minified SignalR script with the unminified version. Then set breakpoints at the beginning of the code (e.g. on the first line with "use strict" within the anonymous function), and at a line that says `$.connection = $.signalR = signalR;` or similar (towards the end).

If neither are hit, then the script is somehow not found at all. If the first one is hit, but the second one isn't, there is some other problem - you could trace it backwards from there. It might be a problem with how you create the Hub, or another configuration problem.

Comment: This problem also occurs if same version of jQuery is referenced twice. In newer templates, jQuery reference is already present at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml, that can easily be missed. Solution is to move this reference to the top of _Layout.cshtml (without creating new one)

Comment: @Lars Hoppner I have set the breakpoints and $.connection is getting initialized, but as soon as the debugging stops, it gets undefined. It works on one layout but doesn't work on the other.